# ¿por qué me sigue apareciendo Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

muy buenos días fíjense que anduve programando en google appscript en una hoja de sheets pero me aparece este error

> 13:03:56  Error
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined
> generatePDFIndividualy  @ Código.gs:26

y pues me puse a investigar en Internet pero parece que en mi caso no hay nada en concreto... aun.
este es mi codigo:

```js
var ColSubDate = 1;
  var ColName = 2;
  var ColAge = 3;
  var ColCivilStatus = 4
  var ColAddres = 5;
  var ColNumExt = 6;
  var ColNumInt = 7;
  var ColSubrb = 8;
  var ColPC = 9;
  var ColCity = 10;
  var ColPR = 11;
  var ColRFC = 12;
  var ColBenefactor = 13;
  var ColMail = 14;
  var XclID = "1eqBrrCztfHZEWwcqbaP90zVfhHVNAZASG-apEFbSWCw"; //new
  var ExlID = "14fTKWX_QukKQERTSWY4E_Lpku5VAAXOo"; //folder
  var TemplateID = "1gMiauWEjUc8PvNBHEkRqold8lF5nJO72W1T343XFyAQ";
  var PdfID = "1OMq5DMTuLF9OKHtcGObdcyK9j5gOJNuK";
  var DocsID = "1PT1XSpvrxFQc4TJzaTD09nvfuL9h0GWs";
  var Urls = 0;

function generatePDFIndividualy(Client){
  var ActiveRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getLastRow();
  var Client = {}
    Client.Date = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColSubDate).getValue;
    Client.Name = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColName).getValue();
    Client.Age = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColAge).getValue();
    Client.CivilStatus = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColCivilStatus).getValue();
    Client.Addres = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColAddres).getValue();
    Client.NumExt = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColNumExt).getValue();
    Client.NumInt = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColNumInt).getValue();
    Client.Subrb = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColSubrb).getValue();
    Client.PC = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColPC).getValue();
    Client.City = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColCity).getValue();
    Client.PR = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColPR).getValue();
    Client.RFC = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColRFC).getValue();
    Client.Benefactor = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColBenefactor).getValue();
    Client.Mail = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColMail).getValue();
    
  var TemplateID = "1gMiauWEjUc8PvNBHEkRqold8lF5nJO72W1T343XFyAQ";
  var PdfID = "1OMq5DMTuLF9OKHtcGObdcyK9j5gOJNuK";
  var DocsID = "1PT1XSpvrxFQc4TJzaTD09nvfuL9h0GWs";

  var TemplateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TemplateID);
  var PDFFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(PdfID);
  var DocsFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(DocsID);
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("formulario"); 

  var TemplateFileCopy = TemplateFile.makeCopy(DocsFile);
  var CopyID =TemplateFileCopy.getId();
  var Namedoc = "CIT de "+ Client.Name + " " + Client.Date; 
  TemplateFileCopy.setName(Namedoc);
  var Docs = DocumentApp.openById(CopyID);
  Docs.setName(Namedoc);
  
  
  //Remplaze variables
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Nombre}}", Client.Name);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Edad}}", Client.Age);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Estado Civil}}", Client.CivilStatus);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Domicilio}}", Client.Addres);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Numero Ext}}", Client.NumExt);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Numero Int}}", Client.NumInt);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Colonia}}", Client.Subrb);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{CP}}", Client.PC);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Ciudad}}", Client.City);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Curp}}", Client.PR);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{RFC}}", Client.RFC);
  Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{Beneficiario}}", Client.Benefactor);

  Docs.saveAndClose();
      var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var paper = source.getSheets()[0];
      
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(XclID);
    paper.copyTo(destination);

  const Pdfblob =Docs.getAs(MimeType.PDF); 
  var PDFcreated = PDFFile.createFile(Pdfblob);
  PDFcreated.addViewer(Client.Mail);
  var Urls ={}
    Urls.PDFurl = PDFcreated.getUrl();
    Urls.Docurl = Docs.getUrl();
    //Urls = generatePDF(Client);
    Client.PDF = Urls.PDFurl;
    //
    var Message = "este es solo una prueba de CIT, descarga aqui el pdf: " + Client.PDF;
    MailSender.sendEmail(Client.Mail, "documento prueba", Message);
    //
}
```

como pueden ver dice que es en la linea 26 sin embargo al hacer debugging aparece que todos los que tienen la variable "Cliente" también aparecen como indefinidos o "undefined" y pues creo que puede ser como esta programado :/
sin embargo no encuentro donde puede estar el error o si alguien sabe del tema que me lo explique ya que no veo por que me sigue apareciendo el error :(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error ocurre porque se llama `Sheet` antes de que esta variable haya sido declarada. Intenta mover

```
var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("formulario");
```

antes de la línea indicada en el mensaje de error.

Notas:

- El código deberá estar en un proyecto contenido por una hoja de cálculo que contenga una hoja llamada `formulario`.
- El código tiene otros errores, por ejemplo, en la línea

  ```
   Client.Date = Sheet.getRange(ActiveRow , ColSubDate).getValue;
  ```

  faltan los paréntesis de `getValue`.